# WARNING in Circular dependency detected: barrelsby Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, circular-dependency

I am getting circular dependency warning while using barrelsby in Angular 10.

```
Error: 
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\core\components\components.module.ts -> src\app\core\components\header\header.component.ts -> src\app\state\index.ts -> src\app\core\components\components.module.ts
```

Structure:

```
/component
  /header
    header.component.ts
    index.ts
```

`index.ts`

```
export * from './header.component';
```

`component.module.ts`

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './header';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent
  ]
})
```

`index.ts`

```
export * from './header/index';
```

Comment: Edit and add content of `header.component.ts` to your question.

Comment: Sometimes you can break the circular dependency by avoiding at some point to import from `index.ts`

Answer (score 3):

It's just a warning so you don't absolutely need to fix it.  The warning tells you where the circle is:

- module imports from header
- header imports from index
- index imports from module

In order to break the circle, I would avoid importing from index.  Whichever component header is importing from index, import it from that components folder instead.

Comment: I have tried importing from component but still it is throwing same.                            import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';